# Access Right for users

Tags: odoo-10, access-rights

In my odoo 10 after several month I am encountering the problem of Access Right for my users. When they want to group the tasks based on project, etc they face the following message:

**Odoo Warning - Access Error
The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.
(Document type: project.project, Operation: read)**

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your error its seems you have to give access rights for project.project model for read. If its given then might be there some record rule for project.project model in your database you have to check it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to Odoo. So how I can edit the Database tables and where I should open the control panel. I worked with phpmyadmin when I was creating websites but for odoo I am not really into pgadmin. :(